# Using dominated convergence theorem to move limit inside the integral

Tags: integration, limits, convergence-divergence

I have to prove that the following limit goes to $0$:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left|u(\omega)\bigg(\frac{2n^2}{\omega^2}(1-\cos(\omega/n))-1\bigg)\right|^2dw$$

where $u \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$.

I want to move the limit inside to that I can substitute:

$$\cos(1/t) = 1 - \frac{1}{2t^2} + \frac{1}{4!t^4} -  \text{...}  $$

And the proof is completed.

I was thinking about using the dominated convergence theorem, but I am not sure how to use it. As a dominating sequence I would use that:

$$1-\cos(t) \leq t^2/2 $$

But then, what else should I make sure of?

Comment: $dt$? I don't see $t$ there :c

Comment: I edited the post to add the missing information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use your inequality to show that
$$ 0 \leq \frac{2(1-\cos(t))}{t^2} \leq 1$$
holds for $t \in \mathbb{R}$ .

If we define $f_n \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ to be your integrand, i.e.
$$ f_n(\omega) = |u(\omega)|^2 \left[1 - \frac{2 (1-\cos(\omega /n))}{(\omega/n)^2}\right]^2 \, , $$
we immediately obtain $|f_n(\omega)| \leq |u(\omega)|^2$ for all $\omega \in \mathbb{R}$ and every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ from the above inequality.

We take $|u|^2$ as the dominating function from the theorem. It is integrable, as we have $u \in L^2 (\mathbb{R})$ . Therefore the dominated convergence theorem allows us to interchange the limit and the integration. But now we are done, since $(f_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ converges to zero pointwise almost everywhere (as mentioned in your question).

Comment: that's a very good solution, thank you! But why would it be wrong to say that:

$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left|u(\omega)\bigg(\frac{2n^2}{\omega^2}(1-\cos(\omega/n))-1\bigg)\right|^2dw \leq \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left|u(\omega)\bigg(\bigg(\frac{2n^2}{\omega^2}\frac{\omega^2}{2n^2}\bigg)-1\bigg)\right|^2dw$

$= \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left|u(\omega)(1-1)\right|^2dw = 0$

Comment: @giovanni_13 Because of the absolute value. We have $|2(1-\cos(x))x^{-2} -1| = 1 - 2(1-\cos(x))x^{-2}$ and now you can use the inequality. But it only shows that this quantity is $\geq 0$ instead of $\leq 0$, so you cannot conclude that all integrals vanish. One must be very careful when applying inequalities to expressions with absolute value bars.

Comment: Thank you very much, now everything is really clear.

Comment: just a doubt: should I also make sure that $f_n(x)$ is a sequence of measurable functions $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: @giovanni_13 That is correct. Since $u \in L^2 (\mathbb{R})$ is measurable, and $\omega \mapsto 1-2(2-\cos(\omega/n)) (\omega/n)^{-2}$ is even continuous, their product and its absolute value squared are indeed measurable.